# Android: how to get vendor id and product id over Bluetooth BR/EDR(classic) mode

Tags: android, bluetooth, hid

I am writing an application to get vendor id and product id of the bluetooth devices. And this works corrctlty on BLE devices, however, I got error status 133 when connect with classic mode devices (unfortunately it is classic mode only). Anyone know how to connectGatt with classic mode deivces?
the code snippet is like the following

```
  private final BluetoothGattCallback bluetoothGattCallback =
      new BluetoothGattCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
          Log.d(TAG, "### onConnectionStateChange status: " + status + ", state: " + newState);
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
          final UUID SERVICE_DEVICE_INFORMATION =
              UUID.fromString("0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");
              List<BluetoothGattService> svclist = gatt.getServices();
              if (svc.getUuid().equals(SERVICE_DEVICE_INFORMATION)) {
                List<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> characteristics = svc.getCharacteristics();
              }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicRead(
            BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
          byte[] value = characteristic.getValue();
          Log.d(TAG, "### onCharacteristicRead:  UUID: " + characteristic.getUuid().toString());
          if (value != null && value.length == 7) {
            Log.d(
                TAG,
                String.format(
                    "### vid:%x pid:%x version:%x",
                    (0xFF & value[1]) | (0xFF & value[2]) << 8,
                    (0xFF & value[3]) | (0xFF & value[4]) << 8,
                    (0xFF & value[5]) | (0xFF & value[6]) << 8));
          }
        }        



  device.connectGatt(context, true, bluetoothGattCallback, device.getType());
```

I tried fetchUuidsWithSdp, and add action for ACTION_UUID, although that does get the HID uuid, 00001124-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb, but no other information part from BASE_UUID and HID UUID.

I also tried device.sdpSearch(BluetoothUuid.Hid), and dump the sdp record in ACTION_SDP_RECORD and no luck.

```
Debug: android.bluetooth.device.extra.SDP_SEARCH_STATUS = "0"
Debug: android.bluetooth.device.extra.DEVICE = "F4:73:35:06:74:3E"
Debug: android.bluetooth.device.extra.SDP_RECORD = "BluetoothSdpRecord [rawData=[], rawSize=0]"
Debug: android.bluetooth.device.extra.UUID = "00001124-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"
```

Comment: You can't connect to classic device as to BLE one because it is absolotely different things. The underlying protocol is absolutely different. The Radio level is absolutely different as well. The HCI commands are also different. BLE device (GATT one) requires GATT API (or at least GATT HCI commands). Classic device requires Classic API. Both communicates over L2CAP but ATT lays above for GATT and HID implemented right above L2CAP.

Comment: Thanks Mike, may I ask what is the corresponding classic API I can use to get vendor and product id? I do see some c code, using sdp to get these information -- Pro Android Games, chapter 8.

Comment: There is no clear method for this. Bluetooth classic devices can also support the [Device Information Service](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/device-information-service-1-1/) (You have already mentioned SDP). However, as this is optional, it is a decision of the developer/manufacturer of a device whether this information is available or not.

Comment: @Lance Bai There is no easy way to get such information from Classic device (except the DIS described by Risto). However if we are talking about HID (you referred it in your original post) the HID Profile provides the way to do that. So you have to read HID profile specification and communicate with your device on L2CAP level. (https://www.bluetooth.org/docman/handlers/downloaddoc.ashx?doc_id=246761)